# Attribute table of a point: longitude, latitude info missing

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, latitude-longitude, geolocation

In my QGIS map I have several vector layers. They all appears on the map well. I am just wondering, where in the Attribute table I can find the information about the geolocation. I supposed that in a point layer I will see in the Attribute table a column for X (longitude) and Y (latitude) for every single point. I hope my question is clear. In other words, how can QGIS know that a specific point is there and not somewhere else, where is the information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to rapidly extract a list of the geolocation for each feature (point), you may simply do a copy-and-paste of your Attribute Table. Firstly, open the Attribute Table and then follow these steps (the step 1 is clicking on the red square for selecting all the point features):

[image]

Then, paste the data (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) to any spreadsheet and you will get the information of you point location as Well Know Text (WKT) (`"AUTO"` is a field already stored in my example dataset, so don't consider it):

[image]

Instead, if you need to work with the lat/long of your points, you may create two new fields in the Attributes Table and use `$y` (for Latitude) and `$x` (for Longitude) for obtaining the information you need:

[image]